# TextView/EditText Explain only 1 line

Tags: android, android-activity, text, scroll, textview

I have created this, with 1 webview and 1 textview (tried also edittext) and a scrollview, but in the preview it explains all lines, when i launch it explain only 1 line. i tried to rmeove scrollview, webview...nothing...how can i do? Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".ActivityMappa"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_mappa"

        >

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/webview" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/testo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="126dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="10"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="@string/testonavi_spawn"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Preview on Android Studio[image]

Preview on my Phone/Emulator

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Couldn't understand anything

Comment: a simple webview, and under a webview, a 30 lines text

Comment: Do you know the use of webview??? Why need webview if you want to display only text?

Comment: no, i use the webview for an zoomable image, the i use twxtview for text...

Comment: but it's not important, if i take off the webview, the textview show me only 1 line

Comment: Post the code that sets the text in the EditText

Comment: Post `testonavi_spawn` from `strings.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `strings.xml` you must escape all `'` of `testonavi_spawn`by `\'`, for example: `...all\'Avamposto...`

> Take a look into the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource) for String resources.

Comment: You cannot set the `layout_height` to `match_parent` under a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Also, why would he want to use a EditText when he wants to display the text.

Comment: for the comment 1st you can although the ide would suggest not to and this would make no difference, for the 2nd don't ask me.

Comment: FYI, It crashes on some phones, faced the issue.. and for 2nd lol.

Comment: Good to know, but the truth is I never use it, so i'll remove it

Comment: This could be it.. mTak is right.. Use escape characters in `Strings.xml`..

Answer (score 1):

Edittext height is given as 126dp. You'll not be able to see 30 lines in it. so make the layout_heigh of the edittext as "wrap_content". This will make the edittext dynamic. As the total content is in scrollview, you'll still be able to scroll and see the complete content

Comment: I tried it too, both in edittext and textview, but nothing, it show only 1 line

Comment: Seems like you are using some special characters. Can you remove single quotes and try it. If it works out, you can use escape characters to use special characters

Comment: replace ' with "'"

Comment: Why?___________

Comment: "'" is considered as single quote in xml. double quotes + single quote + double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

> `android:minLines=10`

where 10 is the number of lines you want it to appear.

Since you have set the `android:width="match_parent"` maybe its going beyond the view change it to `android:layout_width="wrap_parent"`.

**Change the code to:**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/testo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:minLines="10"
        android:text="@string/testonavi_spawn"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
```

> **NOTE:** Always use a `TextView` to display the text and `EditText` to edit any texts.

Comment: i tried this but it does not work, it gives the same problem

Comment: Remove `fillViewPort` in `ScrollView`..Uninstall your application and try reinstalling it. Invalidate caches & restart. There seems to be no problem if you are running the code as mine.. Tried it & works for me..